# Accidental indent in multicols environment

Tags: sectioning, indentation, multicol

I have some ugly (?) code that produces a vertical bar to the left of Sections. All is well until I introduce multicols right after the section start. That gives me an undesired indent for the first line. How can I remedy this?

Visualization:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
% Set font family to sans serif:
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmss}
% Remove subsection numbering:
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
% Create PDF bookmarks:
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
% Smaller margins:
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3cm]{geometry}
% Use symbols for footnotes:
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
% Overload the \section command with left-hanger formatting:
\newcommand{\sectionf}[1]{%
\section[#1]{%
    \rule{-2em}{0em}%
    \rule[-1em]{0.125em}{3em}%
    \rule{1.875em}{0em}%
    #1}
}
% Bullets:
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\cdot$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\cdot$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\cdot$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{$\cdot$}

\begin{document}
\sectionf{Industry Experience}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Health Care\\
Health Insurance\\
Public Health\\
```

Comment: Add `\noindent` before the first line. The start of `multicols` defeats the automatic `\noindent` after `\section`.

Comment: This works as well and is arguably better code - the intent is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the optional argument of `multicols`, i.e., replace

```
\sectionf{Industry Experience}
\begin{multicols}{2}
```

with

```
\begin{multicols}{2}[\sectionf{Industry Experience}]
```