# Place section header outside multicols environment

Tags: sectioning, multicol

Is it possible to do something like

```
...
\end{multicols}
\section{A very long header that looks ugly if it does not span the columns}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor ...
\end{multicols}
\section{Next header}
```

Without the effect that LaTeX thinks my section title does not belong to the following paragraph.

EDIT:

I found the answer here: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41839/accidental-indent-in-multicols-environment?rq=1)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "LaTeX thinks my section title does not belong to the following paragraph"?

Comment: (And welcome to TeX.SX!) And @Werner, I believe he wants to keep the semantic meaning of the document.

Comment: @SeanAllred not just semantics, practical considerations like suppressing indentation of first para of a section, and preventing page break after the heading are affected by the markup

Comment: @SeanAllred I guess that with the correct semantics comes the practical considerations as well